# Write a program that reads the contents of a text file and writes the number of words, upper/lowercase letters and digits into a separate file

Tags: c, file-io

The report file should contain the following:
1. Number of words
2. Number of uppercase letters
3. Number of lowercase letters
4. Number of digits

I have successfully read the file and counted the words letters and digits but i am having issues with writing the contents to the new file, any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define SIZE 40

int main(void)
{
char ch, filename[SIZE];
int digits = 0;
int upper = 0;
int lower = 0;
int entered = 0;
int words = 0;
unsigned long count = 0;
FILE *fp;
printf("Please enter the filename to read: ");
gets(filename);
// "r" reads the file fopen opens the file
if ((fp = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL)
{
    printf("Cannot open the file, %s\n", filename);
}
else
{
    puts("Successfully opened, now reading.\n");

    while ((ch=getc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
       if (isalnum(ch))
       {
           if(!entered)
           {
               entered = 1;
               words++;
           }

       }

       else
       {
            if (entered)
            {
                entered = 0;
            }
       }

       if (isupper(ch))
           {
             upper++;
           }

       else if (islower(ch))
            {
                lower++;
            }
       else if (isdigit(ch))
       {
           digits++;
       }

    }

  }

  fclose(fp); //make sure to close the file if you open one

  char filename2 [SIZE];
  FILE *fp2;

fprintf(stdout, "Please enter the file name to write in: ");
gets(filename2);

if ((fp2 = fopen("filename2", "w")) == NULL)
{
    printf("Cannot create the file, %s\n", filename2);
}
else
{
    fprintf(fp2, "The file \"%s\" has %lu Words.\n", filename, words);
    fprintf(fp2, "The file \"%s\" has %lu Digits.\n", filename, digits);
    fprintf(fp2, "The file \"%s\" has %lu upper case letters.\n", filename, upper);
    fprintf(fp2, "The file \"%s\" has %lu lower case letters.\n", filename, lower);

}

fclose(fp2);


return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
if ((fp2 = fopen("filename2", "w")) == NULL)
```

write

```
if ((fp2 = fopen(filename2, "w")) == NULL)
```

Then, kick yourself.